# in DBSCAN clustering by increasing the cluster size, iterations fluctuates why?

Tags: dbscan

In DBSCAN clustering, by increasing the cluster size for example 1,2,3,4...,  iterations to run fluctuates between i.e for cluster size 2, it took 3 iterations for 4, it took 4 up to 5 only 4 iterations, for 6, increases to 5 then 7 later 5, 4, 4 why is it so? may be nature of dataset I have chosen or some other reason?

Comment: show us sample data and your code

Comment: DBSCAN does not do "iterations". It's not kmeans.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use *large* data to get stable measurements. Most likely, your data set is just way too small.

Make sure to disable turbo boost.

Also repeat each experiments a dozen times, to estimate your measurement error. As long as differences are within the **standard error of the mean** consider them to be just random.